# Connecting to MariaDB from docker-compose Airflow - No module named 'MySQLdb' error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I've modified the docker-compose for Airflow (`apache/airflow:2.5.0-python3.10`) and added in a MariaDB `service:` to emulate the target DB for a project in dev.

In the `_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS` I've included `pymsql` and I am attempting to create a MySQL Connection under `Admin | Connections` and using the MySQL connector to bridge over to Maria (before asking I used `host.docker.internal` as the host name in the Connections| Add Connection field for host).

`apache-airflow-providers-mysql` is already installed as part of the official docker compose for Airflow (and I checked it manually on the container.)

However, every time I hit the Test button I get a `No module named 'MySQLdb'` which I assumed the pip extras install took care of.

Also, I am assuming here I can merely use MySQL over the wire to connect to the mariadb via python but if there additional libraries or installs needed (for example, libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev python3-mysqldb or similar to be installed, please let me know. I assume someone else has had to do this already, though perhaps not from docker... =] I am trying to avoid building my own image and use the existing docker-compose, but if it's unavoidable and I need to do a `build .`, lemme know.).

I am concerned this may be due to the fact I am on an M1 Mac laptop running this (as 2 requirements, I've now dug down and researched have a  `platform_machine != "aarch64"` against them  8-/  Surely there is a way around this though, yeah? Esp with docker? (do I need to do a custom build?). Also, do not understand why these particular components would not work on arm64 at this point that macs have been chipped like that over 2 years.

thanks!
PS> Maria is not supported as a backend in Airflow but Connections to it as a database should work much like anything else that can connect via sqlalchemy etc.

Set up the Connection in Airflow and then installed the extra pip for `pymysql`. However, I still seem to be getting the same No module named 'MySQLdb' error on test connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the MySql provider for Airflow:

```bash
pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

or add it to your requirements file, it should install all what you need to use MySql/MariaDB as connection.

Comment: Hey @hussein-awala, thanks for weighing in but that provider is already installed in the docker-compose for apache/airflow. This does not appear to be the problem. Just in case, I manually verified it with 

```bash
$ default@b053bde47c99:/opt/airflow$ pip list | grep -i apache-airflow-providers-mysql

$ apache-airflow-providers-mysql           3.4.0
```
It's there. I believe the issue may be I am on ARM64 on the Mac.  8-/

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be one where Airflow's MySQL operators have a != aarch64 for the Apple OSX and my machine was an M1 chipped laptop.

How did I get around  this? In my docker-compose for the airflow components I set a directive of `platform: x86_64` in the service(s) and then rebuild the container. After that, I had no problem connecting with the MySQL connector to the MariaDB that we had as a target.

note: this greatly increased the startup time for the docker compose instance (from like 20s to 90s-ish, but works). As a solution for dev, worked great.